# Compose Tagless Final Return Types in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a repo service that uses Tagless final and it looks like this:

```
final class MyRepoImpl[M[_]: Async](transactor: DoobieTransactor[M])(implicit ec: Scheduler)
  extends MyRepo[M] {

  override def isKnownElement(modelName: String): M[Boolean] = ???

  override def isUpdateRequired(modelName: String): M[Boolean] = ???
    
  override def currentDatePostgres(): M[String] = ???
}
```

I then have a service that calls this Repo like this:

```
final class Myservice[M[_]] {
  
  def myMethod(id: Int): M[SomeReturnType] = {
    // How can I compose isKnownElement first and if the return is true, process the isUpdateRequired and based on the response, I would like to return SomeReturnType
  }
}
```

All I want to do is to compose the two mehods in the Repo class in my service class. I tried doing flatMap, but I do not find that signature. My repo trait looks like this:

```
trait MyRepo[M[_]] {
  override def isKnownElement(modelName: String): M[Boolean] = ???    
  override def isUpdateRequired(modelName: String): M[Boolean] = ???
  override def currentDatePostgres(): M[String] = ???
}
```

I want to acheive the following:

1. If isKnownElement returns true, I want to check isUpdateRequired and if isUpdateRequired returns true, I need to return SomeResultType which contains a status field with status Rejected
2. If isKnownElement returns false, I would like to return SomeResultType with status Rejected
3. If isKnownElement returns true and isUpdateRequired returns false, I need to return SomeResultType with status Accepted

How can I elegantly map this elegantly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to ensure that `isUpdateRequired` is only called if and only if `isKnownElement` returns `true`

```scala
import cats.Monad
import cats.syntax.all.*

final class Myservice[M[_]: Monad](
  repository: MyRepo[M]
) {
  def myMethod(id: Int): M[SomeReturnType] =
    repository.isKnownElement(modelName = ???).flatMap {
      case true =>
        repository.isUpdateRequired(modelName = ???).map {
          case true =>
            SomeReturnType(status = Rejected)

          case false =>
            SomeReturnType(status = Accepted)
        }

      case false =>
        IO.pure(SomeReturnType(status = Rejected))
    }
}
```

If you can just call both operations *(either sequentially or in parallel)*

```scala
import cats.Monad
import cats.syntax.all.*

final class Myservice[M[_]: Monad](
  repository: MyRepo[M]
) {
  def myMethod(id: Int): M[SomeReturnType] =
    // You may use parMapN if you want to call both methods in parallel.
    (
      repository.isKnownElement(modelName = ???),
      repository.isUpdateRequired(modelName = ???)
    ).mapN {
      case (true, false) => SomeReturnType(status = Accepted)
      case (true, true) => SomeReturnType(status = Rejected)
      case (false, _) => SomeReturnType(status = Rejected)
    }
}
```

You can also use `for`, `if / else`, and many other syntactical changes depending on your style.
But, the core idea remains, you just compose programs. Nothing fancy.

> PS: This is a good example of Boolean blindless, you may use some ADTs instead of booleans so the pattern match version reads better.

Comment: Yes, something like this but want to avoid nesting. Here in the case true, I need to call another method that returns a Boolean and do a pattern match on that. I want to possible avoid that!

Comment: I updated my question with my requirement!